# Disable git merge conflicts on on non-conflicting changes to subsequent lines

Tags: git

If two subsequent lines are changed in different branches, merging
will result in conflict even if there isn't any.
Invoking merge tool will mark file as resolved automatically.

Is there a way to disable this behavior ? I want the merge to happen
automatically if possible.

Ideally, this would be configurable per file type.

Answer (score 0):

Git works off of lines of context and the idea of patches. The boundary of the change is the 2 lines (one above and one below) that didn't change. In your case, those don't add up. This is Git being cautious in not allowing this. The merge tools have a different opinion. It's better to err on the side of caution.

There is no way to disable this behaviour unless you patch git itself.

Comment: That does not answer the question. I really need git to be less cautious, ideally only for certain file types.

Comment: Edit the answer as per your comment.